# javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2342)

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, glassfish-4, hibernate-5

## Getting issue while accessing local beans

EJB3, Hibernate 5, JPA2, Glassfish 
Searched on internet but didn't found any solution.
I recetly moved code from jpa2.0, hibernate4 to jpa 2.1 and hibernate5. Also changed glassfish 3.0 to 4.1.2. Earlier it is working fine but after I changed the libraries its not working.

```
[#|2018-07-04T17:03:38.674+0530|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1|com.hootboard.service.PostHootServices|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(5);_TimeMillis=1530704018674;_LevelValue=1000;|
      javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2342)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postI`enter code here`nvoke(BaseContainer.java:2123)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy397.processDiscussions(Unknown Source)
        at com.hootboard.session.ItemFacadeBean.startPostProcess(ItemFacadeBean.java:2753)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy387.startPostProcess(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.SharedCDRClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(SharedCDRClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:119)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.invoke(ClientDelegateImpl.java:258)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:198)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
        at com.hootboard.remote.__ItemFacadeBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.startPostProcess(com/hootboard/remote/__ItemFacadeBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
        at com.hootboard.remote._ItemFacadeBeanRemote_Wrapper.startPostProcess(com/hootboard/remote/_ItemFacadeBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
        at com.hootboard.service.PostHootServices.postHootService(PostHootServices.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:666)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:511)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
        ... 106 more
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2342)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2123)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy381.setFreeBoardVisibilityMDB(Unknown Source)
        at com.hootboard.session.PostHootProcessFacade.processesOnSuccess(PostHootProcessFacade.java:2044)
        at com.hootboard.session.PostHootProcessFacade.processDiscussions(PostHootProcessFacade.java:976)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
        ... 104 more
    Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.useClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:361)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.preInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:255)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4524)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1986)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
        ... 137 more
    |#]
```

## Tried Solutions

### Added transaction strategy to required, no success

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird exception and also it seems that you've changed a lot (Since glassfish comes with EclipseLink as its default ORM).

Could you please add some more context from where does that exception is being thrown?